# Can a minor copyright or trademark?

Tags: copyright, trademark

Am I allowed as a minor to copyright materials and trademark names in Utah?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Federal law governing copyright, and state and federal law governing trademark, do not make any stipulations about the person enjoying the particular property right. In lieu of a specific restriction, the person may be an alien, a prisoner, a public employee, a corporation, or an astronaut. There are limits on minors and contracts, but no contract is required to write a book, make a sculpture, or create a distinctive business mark. (Those limits potentially raise questions about a minor signing away their author's rights if they create a work for hire, which you didn't ask about. A contract is typically necessary to profit off of such a creation, but not always). The [copyright office even says](https://www.copyright.gov/help/faq/faq-who.html#minor) that you can register copyright (important, registration is necessary to get maximal protection). There is a bit of an issue that a minor has limited ability to sue (for infringement), so in Utah [Rule 17](http://www.utcourts.gov/resources/rules/urcp/urcp017.html) you would need a guardian to sue for you, likewise in federal court ([same number!](https://www.law.cornell.edu/rules/frcp/rule_17)).